# Python: Filter a dictionary key using list of strings

Tags: python, dictionary, search, filter, keyword

I have a dictionary that contains a key with a list of values that are strings.

```
d = {'docs':['1_a', '2_a', '3_b', '4_c', '4_d']}
```

I'd like to filter `d['docs']` with a filter list like `['a', '4']`, so that I get:

```
['1_a', '2_a', '4_c', '4_d']
```

The filter list could have numerous keywords not just two. I've looked in to list comprehension and failed.

Comment: what is expected output?

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question.

Comment: @HarshaBiyani Thought I wrote that pretty clearly - even with the expected output. Numerous people answered below very quickly, so I must have done something right in writing my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just search if `any` of the search terms appear in your values:

```
d = {'docs':['1_a', '2_a', '3_b', '4_c', '4_d']}
search = ['a', '4']
out = [val for val in d['docs'] if any(s in val for s in search)]

print(out)
# ['1_a', '2_a', '4_c', '4_d']
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It is exactly what I was after. Ended up that I actually wanted "all" instead of "any", but your answer got me there and answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```py
>>> d = {'docs':['1_a', '2_a', '3_b', '4_c', '4_d']}
>>> search = ['a', '4']
>>> [x for x in d['docs'] if any(s in x for s in search)]
['1_a', '2_a', '4_c', '4_d']
```

Comment: Cheers. Exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution, not sure if it is what you're looking for.

```
d = {'docs':['1_a', '2_a', '3_b', '4_c', '4_d']}
filter = ['a', '4']
result = []

for i in (d['docs']):
    
    for f in filter:
        if f in i:
            result.append(i)

print(result)
```

> [image]

Comment: Thanks. The list comprehension from the other answers is a little slicker though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `filter()` to filter elements from a list:

```
list(filter(lambda x: any(i in x for i in ['a', '4']), d['docs']))
```

```
['1_a', '2_a', '4_c', '4_d']
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the OP got what they wanted, but this is mostly typed so I might as well post it. If the idea is to work with [slugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL#Slug) then the accepted answer could cause strange results.

For example:

```
>>> d = {'docs': ['2_at', '2_hat', '34_b', '4_c', '32_bat']}
>>> search = ['at', '4']
>>> [val for val in d['docs'] if any(s in val for s in search)]
['2_at', '2_hat', '34_b', '4_c', '32_bat']
```

Instead, you could split each item:

```
>>> d = {'docs': ['2_at', '2_hat', '34_b', '4_c', '32_bat']}
>>> search = ['at', '4']
>>> [val for val in d['docs'] if any(s in val.split('_') for s in search)]
['2_at', '4_c']
```